# How to properly partialSign a transaction? (Signature verification failed)

Tags: transactions, signature, signing

I'm trying bundle an [OrcaSwap tx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@orca-so/sdk) with another transaction. The thing is, I'm getting a "Signature verification failed" error when trying to serialize the transaction. My code goes something like this:

```
const existingTransaction = ...;
const swapPayload = await orcaPool.swap(payer, inputToken, amountIn, minAmountOut);

// so that the swap is called first before the existing tx
const transaction = swapPayload.tx.add(existingTransaction);

// finalizeTransaction() just adds blockhash and lastValidBlockHeight
// technically this is unneeded but the call is part of a larger function
// so I just kept it this way
finalizeTransactions(transaction);

// partially sign with orca signers
transaction.partialSign(...swapPayload.signers);
```

I then attempt to sign the transaction with my payer Keypair, but it fails here:

```
transaction.sign(user);
// fails here 
const rawTx = transaction.serialize();
const signature = await sendAndConfirmRawTransaction(connection, rawTx, opts);
```

I have made sure that the transaction is not modified in anyway after `partialSign`, aside from being finally signed by my keypair. Pretty much stuck at this point, would appreciate any help or hints to a solution.

To add (not sure if this is relevant) but I'm on localnet with the relevant OrcaPool account infos. I assume this isn't related as it fails on `serialize()` but thought I'd mention it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`Transaction.sign()` resets all existing signatures in the transaction https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/ef5a6daf1c404b51bdda186274a955276c8b6e90/src/transaction/legacy.ts#L617. I've run into the same problem since the `Transaction.sign()` docs didn't seem totally clear about this.

Just use `Transaction.partialSign()` for all signatures and you should be okay.

Comment: I concur - when I was trying on localnet (I was signing transactions via test scripts rather than a normal WalletAdapter), the solution was to just `sign()` with `signers` set to `[...signers, keypair]` rather than separating the signing. 

When using with a WalletAdapter, it works to `partialSign`, and then do `wallet.signTransaction()`. While your answer is correct, it doesn't directly answer the question. Would still love to know if it's possible to sign a partially-signed transaction when running unit tests.

Comment: @Kurt I mean to use `Transaction.partialSign()` multiple times on the same tx and never use `Transaction.sign()`. ie where you are performing the second signing of your transaction as `transaction.sign(user)`, replace that with `transaction.partialSign(user)`. You can just replace all the places you were calling `sign()` with `partialSign()`. WalletAdapter's `signTransaction()` method works more like `partialSign()` in that it doesn't delete existing signatures, so that's why it was working for you where `Transaction.sign()` was not.